# How to update Future builder data after change in data

Tags: flutter, future

I am rendering api response data through FutureBuilder. I have an api which give me the title, content and another end point for the thumbnail link. In my code my listview need thumnail and title. So what I am doing is , first time call the api and get the title and content and empty link into my User constructor,  when my userData is filled by first api call , it rendered the title in the list withou waiting for the thumnail. Then i call 'whencomplete' statement in init function to call second api to get thumnail link. second api call get the get the images and then i update the user object of of User class which is globale object. but Future builder doesnot notify the change in the data, then I use SetState to  notify the state that user data has been changed . But dublicate item populate in the list which is in future buidler. why it make dublicate? How to handle this using Futurebuidler when data is changed?

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: userData,
        initialData: null,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              break;
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("Loading ...",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red))),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.separated(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title.toString()),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                        },
                        leading:
                            snapshot.data[index].links.toString().isEmpty
                                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                                : Image.network(snapshot.data[index].links),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                      ));
                    });
              }
              break;
            default:
              return Container();
          }
        }),
  ),
);
```

Here is init function

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    userData = getUsers().whenComplete(() {
      getImages();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Here is my first APi Call

```
  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    var data =
        await http.get("https://primest.tv/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1");
    var jsonDataText = json.decode(data.body);
    linksArray.clear();
    int o=0;
    for (var u in jsonDataText) {
      String title = u["title"]['rendered'];
      String content = u["content"]['rendered'];
      String maper = u["_links"]['wp:featuredmedia'][0]["href"];
      linksArray.add(maper);
      User userr = User(title, content, '');
      user.add(userr);
      o++;
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Here is my second Api cal for thumnails

```
  Future<List<User>> getImages() async {
    int i = 0;
    for (var userDataItem in linksArray) {
      var data2 = await http.get(userDataItem);
      var jsonData2 = json.decode(data2.body);
      String imageLink = jsonData2["link"];
      user.insert(i, User(user[i].title, user[i].content, imageLink));
      i++;
    }
```

// using setState to update the data in future builder
 setState(() {
      user=user;
    });
        return user;
      }

Here is User class

```
class User {
  String title, content, links;
  User(this.title, this.content, this.links);
  User.from(String link) {
    this.links = link;
  }
}
```

Comment: make an `async` method that calls: `userData = await getUsers(); imagesData = await getImages();` or simply use `Future.wait()`

Comment: I want to display whatever i got in first api response(title and content), I dont want to unneccessary wait for the images and then display, inshort I dont want to wait till the second api response and then display all the data,

Comment: every api has 7 sec latency rate, so if i wait for both api to complete it takes me 15 sec which is irretating for user some times time exceeded to 30 sec, so that is why i want to do part by part

Comment: so maybe you need a `StreamBuilder` as it can be "fired" multiple times?

Comment: you mean there is no fire mechanism in future builder?

Comment: future builder "fires" only once - when its `Future` is completed - but if you dont want `StreamBuilder` you could just use a raw `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` twice

Comment: Thank you @pskink , I am moving to the StreamBuider i was not awre of this in future builder.

Comment: ok, if you are brave enough... just curious, how do you want to create your `Stream`? and add some data to?

Comment: Yes I am brave and curious too. I will make a stream type of list<User> and then I hope so when this object will change , it will notify the UI.

Comment: but you need a `Stream` if you want to use `StreamBuilder` - so how do you want to create that `Stream`?

Comment: I want to create userData object, that should be stream object/instance. If  you are asking how i will create a steam then i have no idea about stream. I will see some material to check how stream works

Comment: ok, good luck then ;-)